# Special characters from xml file in flash not showing

Tags: xml, flash, character-encoding

I have a flash template for a website and i can't get it working with special characters like šđćčž

The main page of template is about us and it consists of

```
index.html
index.fla
index.swf
```

index page is basically flash container which do animation but loading files from other pages like news, about us, contact, gallery.

The page that i want to load is about us and it consists of

```
about_us.fla
about_us.swf
```

And about_us page load text content from about_us.xml file

At first some of you would say to check if those characters are included in flash file and if font supports it. So i opened index.fla file and embeded those characters and also selected all characters in character range. I made sure that font support special characters by opening photoshop and checking if characters will display correctly if i type there.

I also opened index.html file and converted encoding from ANSI to utf-8, and in meta tag i set charset=utf-8

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

And i also opened about_us.xml file, which is holding text to display on website and converted encoding from ANSI to utf-8, and also set xml encoding="utf-8"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

But still no luck, i tried few different combinations and i can't get it working

So on website if i write:

```
Dobrodošli
Ovo je zvanična prezentacija naših domaćih proizvoda.
```

Instead of this i get:

```
Dobrodoli
Ovo je zvanina prezentacija naih domaih proizvoda.
```

I need to implement characters from Serbian Latin language so these are characters like ŠšĐđČčĆćŽž but i can't get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution by my self. Everyone keep suggesting me to embed fonts in flash and set my xml files to utf-8 which is correct.

But template i was editing was made in flash 8 and i am using flash cs6 so when i publish it, it was converted to flash cs6 and that mada it to not work somehow, when i set to publish in flash 8 compatibility, now i see fonts, and template works.

Answer (score 1):

I have not had this issue myself, but maybe this might help?

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/System.html#useCodePage

It looks like you would need to set useCodePage to false.

Is your text rendering in the swf or in html?

Edit: I've noticed that certain fonts can also cause trouble. Have you tried a different (preferably system rather than embedded) font?